# Why my MUI's TextField is rendering the emoji selected using "Emoji-picker-react" as [object Object] instead of actual emoji (how to resolve it)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on making a feature where user would be able to select a particular emoji from

```
<EmojiPicker /> component exported from **'emoji-picker-react'**.
```

But the problem is instead of rendering the actual emoji inside of the MUI's TextField, it is rendering a string of [object Object].

I know, that MUI's TextField behaves this way only, as it is expecting a string, so it is converting the EmojiData into a string and thus getting it rendered as [object Object].

But, my question is, how could I dispose this problem and convert the data (the selected emoji) using emoji-picker-react into the emoji only.

Is there any other way my emoji could be displayed as emoji ( instead of `[Object of type object]`? ).

I have tried multiple input fields including the basic `<textarea />` and `<input />` from basic HTML, but all they are returning the `[object Object]` only.

I am attaching what I have done so far to accomplish the goal inside of the below mentioned sandbox -

Please check this below mentioned sandbox for better grasp of my situation -
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-davinci-8d3p7v?file=/src/App.tsx

I would like you to check it and correct, **(either by applying a little different approach)** or any way around, such that the textfield would be able to show the emoji selected.

Also please tell me, if I have to select the *words* and *emojies* together, how am I going to do this (inside of react **useState()**) ?

I would highly appreciate your suggestions/corrections .
Thank you in advance !

Comment: `ShowEmoji` returns a reactnode which will works fine in typography. But you cannot render reactnode in input field.

Comment: So what could be the possible alternative for this? How could I get the value of emoji into my text field. You have my sandbox please help me.

Comment: I have no knowledge about emojis. But i can give you my suggestion. If you inspect the any emoji, it loading the image from cdn and uses img tag. a div with content editable (like  rich text) can solve this issue. when you select an emoji, create an img tag with correct src and use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to append the emoji. Or you can have a look at [EmojiBase](https://emojibase.dev/)